# PHP number thousand separator in syntax

Tags: php, syntax, numbers

My code has some long constant numbers. To avoid mistakes, I want to declare numbers with thousand separators. In Java 7, I can do this:

```
int MyConst = 1_000_000;   ///The token '_' (thousand separator) make it more clearance
```

How can I do that in PHP?

Comment: `$myConst = 1000000;` ?

Comment: you can't use seperator like java7 in php. but you can use strings with seperator. but before use them you must convert to original types. for example MyConst = "1_000_000"; int MyIntConst = cast_to_int(MyConst); function cast_to_int(str) { return (int) str_replace("_", "", str); } somethinglike that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP does not offer such feature. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

You could use scientific notation to represent big numbers: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php but then again, your integers would be actually floats and you'd probably have to add typecasting.

Comment: This accepted answer is now outdated: The first link illustrates that this syntax was added in 7.4

Answer (score 1):

In php you simply declare `$myVar = 1000000;`

From [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

Answer (score 1):

in php we do like this

```
$input = 1000000;
$output = number_format( $input , 0 , '.' , '_' );
echo $output;
```

output : 1_000_000

Answer (score 1):

This syntax was added in [7.4](https://php.watch/versions/7.4/underscore_numeric_separator). Since then, you can use the underscore for this just like in Java. However, what you can't do is this:

- Two or more underscores: `1__6`
- Underscores before and after the number: `_16` and `16_`
- Underscore around the decimal point: `1_.6` or `1._6`
- Underscore around the e in scientific notation: `1.6_e-28` or `1.6e_-28`
- Underscore around the b in binary notation: `0_b01010` or `0b_010101`
- Underscore around the x in hex notation: `0_xf00d` or `0x_food`